# How to modify list of lists using str.format() so floats are 3 decimals and other data types remain the same

Tags: python-3.x, list, types, formatting

I have a list of lists that is very big, and looks like this:

`list_of_lists = [[0,'pan', 17.892, 4.6555], [4, 'dogs', 19.2324, 1.4564], ...]`

I need to modify it using the str.format() so the floats go to 3 decimal places and the rest of the  data stays in its correct format. I also need to add a tab between each list entry so it looks organized and somewhat like this:

```
0   'pan'   17.892   4.655
4   'dogs'  19.232   1.456
...
```

And so on.

My problem is that I keep getting the error in my for loop and gow to fix it.

```
for x in list_of_lists:
    print ("{:.2f}".format(x))

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you are iterating through a nested list. This means that `x` is also a list itself, and not a valid argument to the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) function.

If the number of elements in the inner lists are small and it makes sense in the context of the problem, you can simply list all of them as arguments:

```
list_of_lists = [[0,'pan', 17.892, 4.6555], [4, 'dogs', 19.2324, 1.4564]]

for x in list_of_lists:
    print ("{:d}\t{:s}\t{:.3f}\t{:.3f}".format(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
```

These are now tab delimited, and the floats have three decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for x in list_of_lists:
    print ("{:.2f}".format(x))
```

This is only looping over the top level array - not the elements inside - therefore you are getting the error.

Try addressing the element individually

```py
# build manually, join with tab-char and print on loop 
for i in s:
    result = []
    result.append( f'{i[0]}' )
    result.append( f'{i[1]}' )
    result.append( f'{i[2]:.3f}' )
    result.append( f'{i[3]:.3f}' )
    print( '\t'.join(result) )

# build in one line and print
for i in s:
    print( f'{i[0]}\t\'{i[1]}\'\t{i[2]:.3f}\t{i[3]:.3f}'
```

Or as a list comprehension

```py
# build whole line from list comprehension, join on new-line chat
result = [f'{i[0]}\t\'{i[1]}\'\t{i[2]:.3f}\t{i[3]:.3f}' for i in s]
result = '\n'.join(result)
print(result

# all in one line
print( '\n'.join([f'{i[0]}\t\'{i[1]}\'\t{i[2]:.3f}\t{i[3]:.3f}' for i in s]))
```